# Which sentence is correct? Using suggest or suggests in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, sentence

I was wondering which sentence is correct:
"Koenig and Eagly **suggests** that that stereotype formation is perceived by relying on schemas of what people perceive as typical of a group..."

or

"Koenig and Eagly **suggest** that that stereotype formation is perceived by relying on schemas of what people perceive as typical of a group..."

Please help, I'm still confused with subject verb agreements and sentence fragmentation.

Thanks!

Comment: It's plural unless, according to the style of what is apparently an academic journal, it is interpreted to mean "The article by Koenig and Eagly."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the subject of the clause is present-tense third-person plural, you would use **suggest**.

In first- or second-person, or third-person plural, you use "suggest."  Use "suggests" in third-person singular.

First person:

> I **suggest** that you stay.

Second person:

> You **suggest** that I go.

Third person plural:

> They **suggest** that we go.

Third person singular:

> She **suggests** that he go.

In your sentence, there are two people, so it's plural.

> Koenig and Eagly **suggest**...

If you wanted to, in your example, you could also use past-tense third-person plural:

> Koenig and Eagly **suggested**...

Comment: @ITSLIT if this answered your question, you could mark the answer as accepted. :)